# Print values of a struct

Tags: solidity, meteor

I'm developing a dapp on Meteor that uses a contract written in solidity.
In the contract there is a struct.
Is possible to print the values that are in the struct? How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single Struct that you want to get the value for, you can (1) simply make it a public variable or (2) create a getter in the contract, something like `getStruct` below:

```
struct MyStruct {
  uint a;
  uint b;
  uint c;
}

MyStruct public myStruct = MyStruct(1, 2, 3);

function getStruct()
  constant
  returns (uint a, uint b, uint c)
{
  return (myStruct.a, myStruct.b, myStruct.c);
}
```

For your DApp, if the Struct is public, you can simply just call that variable in web3, `contractInstance.myStruct.call()` which returns and array `[a,b,c]`;

Or you can use the getter function (`contractInstance.getStruct()`) which would return an array `[a, b, c]`.

Comment: What is the _address parameter?

Comment: @GiulioMagnanini I changed the response to just get the single MyStruct values.  My previous response assumed you'd have multiple Structs indexed by an address (`mapping (address => MyStruct) public myList`), so you would retrieve a Struct relating to an input address (`_` in `_address` simply denotes an input, just code styling) by something like `myList[_address]`.